# How the super constructor works in flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

In **`Dart`**, I understand how `super` works like this :

```
class Foo {
  Foo(int a, int b) {
    //Code of constructor
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  Bar(int a, int b) : super(a, b);
}
```

I don't really get what is happening when `super` is used in the `cubit`(or `blocs`) classes of `flutter_bloc`.

I'm not understanding for example when the `CounterCubit` class extends `Cubit` : `CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState>` and the `CounterState` class can be used as a parameter for the `cubit`.

```
class CounterState {
  int counterValue;
  CounterState({@required this.counterValue});
}



class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(CounterState(counterValue: 0));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The super constructor calls the constructor of the parent class.
The cubit in flutter_bloc is defined as.

```
abstract class Cubit<State> extends BlocBase<State> {
  Cubit(State initialState) : super(initialState);
}
```

The State is just a generic class type here and can be of any type you want.
You can learn more about generics [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics)
A very simple code for making a counter cubit is.

```
class CounterCubit extends Cubit<int> {
   CounterCubit() : super(0);

}
```

The `Cubit<int>` means your State here is of type `int` and `super(0)` sets the initial value state value to "0" as your value is type int. *So essentially the super constructor of a cubit takes in the value of the initial state.*

In your case:

```
class CounterState {
  int counterValue;
  CounterState({@required this.counterValue});
}



class CounterCubit extends Cubit<CounterState> {
  CounterCubit() : super(CounterState(counterValue: 0));
}
```

The `Cubit<CounterState>` means your State here is of type CounterState (which is a class you declared yourself above) and `super(CounterState(counterValue: 0))` initializes an object with `counterValue=0` and that object is passed as the initial state via super constructor.

I hope this clarifies your question. Do let me know if my explanation was not clear enough for you